# How Remember Me for email id Works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xib

I have created one Login Screen where user enter their mail id.

But i want to insert one functionality where it should list the mail id automatically when user type first character of mail id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one way. I don't know how much feasible it is. So the Idea is : You can store somewhere all the email id after log in success. For example in sqlite database. Now, Implement Notification center for "UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" and search for the character in database when user start typing in TextField and show UITableview underneath UITextField with match results (which start from entered character).

When user tap on any cell of Tablview hide tableview and take that cell label value in UITextField. That's it. Hope this logic work.

Comment: @Rupesh, you should mention what you have thought about and some code if you have implemented so that people get a better view of what you are looking for.

Comment: Why don't you just keep persistent login So user just need to login once and session stored until logout manually. You can store username and password in NSUSerDefault. That would be pretty easy and straight forward. Most of the apps doing like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the emaid id in UserDefaults & use it whereever you want